# Using JQuery $.GET and $.POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

You'll have to forgive the naivety of my question.  I'm fairly familiar with using PHP, HTML, and CSS.  However, I'm trying to write a simple statistical collector for a small project.  I've poured over many different examples of using either jQuery or Ajax for this.  I decided on using jQuery as my first approach.  The goal is to import the values from the getinfo.php file, assign them to variables, then post the collected information to a database for later analysis.  However, I've run into a bit of a snag..  I'm using the $.GET request to pull in this php file.

GETINFO.PHP

```
<?php
$browserID = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ip = $_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url = $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'];

echo $browserID;
echo $ip;
echo $url;
?>
```

Fairly straight forward for my example, nothing extremely fancy.  For my jQuery get and post request I wrote this.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            // Define variables to send
            var pageTag = "Test Text";

            // Retrieve PHP variables
            $.get("getinfo.php", function (data) {

                alert("Data:" + data)

                // Post data to database
                $.post("process.php",{
                        page: pageTag

                    },
                    function (response,status){//required callback function
                        alert("*----Received Data----*\n\nResponse : " + response+"\n\nStatus : " + status);
                        //"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.

                });
            });
        });
  </script>
```

As you can see it's a mess, yes I'm a beginner and I except that.  Anyway, so separately these two pieces of code work fine.  However, when I try to combine them, I am not getting the results I need.  My `var pageTag = "Test Text";` is not even getting pushed over to the server when the actual post takes place.  Now my PostgreSQL data base is getting blank entries save the time stamp, but that's being submitted by the process.php file itself.

PROCESS.PHP

```
 <?php
  #Creds to access the database
  require_once("connection.php");

  /* Log page and get filenames */
  #$page = input($_GET['page']) or die('ERROR: Missing page ID');
  $page = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['page']));
  $ip_add = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['ip_addy']));
  $browser = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['browser']));
  $timestampInSeconds = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
  $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $timestampInSeconds);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO stats (page, date, ip, browser) VALUES ('$page','$date','$ip_add','$browser')";
  pg_query($db,$sql);

  echo $page;
  echo $ip_add;
  echo $date;

  $query="SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM stats WHERE page= '$page'";
  $result = pg_query($db,$query);
  $row = pg_fetch_array($result,0,PGSQL_NUM);
  $count = $row[0];

  $query = "SELECT count(distinct IP) FROM stats WHERE page= '$page'";
  $result = pg_query($db,$query);
  $row = pg_fetch_array($result,0,PGSQL_NUM);
  $UniaquCount = $row[0];
  pg_close($db);

  exit();
```

So, for a quick recap.  I need to use getinfo.php to pull in some data from the client side then post those requests via jquery to process.php for delivery to the database.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should try encoding the response of Process.php in JSON, on second thought, you are not sending any response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big Thanks to everyone that assisted me on this.  Here is the final snippet of code I used for the ajax request:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            // Create the AJAX request
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",                                       // Using the POST method
                url: "getinfo.php",                                 // The file to call
                dataType: "json",                                   // Our data to pass

                success: function (data) {                               // What to do on success
                    //On success define the following variables from getinfo.php
                    var ip = JSON.stringify(data["ip"]);
                    var url = JSON.stringify(data["url"]);
                    var browser = JSON.stringify(data["browser"]);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",        //Using the POST method
                        url: "process.php",  //The php file used to submit data to database
                        dataType: "text",    // Our data to pass
                        cache: false,
                        data: {
                            page: url,
                            browser: browser,
                            ip_addy: ip,

                        },
                        success: function (response, status) {
                            alert("*----Received Data----*\n\nResponse : " + response + "\n\nStatus : " + status);

                        }
                    });

                },
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The ajax request pulls in the requested data then posts that data to the PostgeSQL database.  Thank you again everyone!  I hope this helps out someone else trying to figure out this same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending anything back in your Process.php file.

Try the following:

```
$data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Use this at the end of the process.php after preparing all the data. You don't necessarily need the `status` parameter. Just make your data in whatever format you want.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, please bare with me I'm trying get this.  I'm only using process.php to send the data over to the database.  If I exclude the $.get request and just use the $.post, it works just fine.  So, I'm not sure what I would need to send "back" to the jQuery request?  Unless, I'm just misunderstanding what you are telling me.

Comment: Your Process.php is not sending any response back to the AJAX. What you need to do at the end of process.php copy the following code and paste `$data = "Test Response"; header('Content-Type: application/json'); echo json_encode($data);` and see what happens

Comment: also remove `json_decode` from your POST variables and try

Comment: Thank you very much for replying so quickly!  You were placing me on the right track, at the time I didn't get it.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

There are numbers of mistakes.

First, in your "getinfo.php", use `json` respond properly. Like:

```
$data = array(
             "browserid"=>$browserID,
             "ip"=>$ip,
             "url"=>$url,
             );
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then in your jQuery Ajax, first, set the Data Type to: "json", and then parse it. Like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "getinfo.php",
  success: function(data) {
      var browserid = data["browserid"];
      var ip = data["ip"];
      var url = data["url"];
      //
      // Continue, the POST part (or) whatever you want here..
      //
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey everyone, I apologize for the long wait on my reply.  I'm just now getting back to this piece of code.  I made the changes to the getinfo.php and now I'm getting the json output.  I also changed my ajax per @夏期劇場 suggestion.  I'm now successfully, getting an output when I use `alert();`.  At this point I'm working on the posting portion of the code.  Separately, it works fine, however once nested, it's not receiving the data from the $.GET request.  That is where I'm at now.